# How to decrease sequence generator of dataset PK field using delphi

Tags: transactions, sequence, firebird

I want to decrease a sequence generator of dataset ( PK FIELD) after doing a rollback.
I am using FreePascal  with Firebird.

Comment: I do not think, this is a good idea (if it is even possible): Think about concurrent users: User A starts transaction, incrementing sequence, then user B starts transaction and finish successful but later A fails ... you get the point?

Comment: I agree with you .I will abandon this idea and redefine PK as bigint.